# Error: 1 is an integer literal, not a string, for entry

Tags: bibtex

I am using the `natbib` package and a custom `.bst` file. I am not very familiar with LaTeX unfortunately. The document is able to compile and produce a PDF, but I dont know what the error means. I am using MiKTeX and TeXstudio. This is my `.bib` entry:

```
@book{fysikbog,
title = {Physics for Scientists and Engineers, 7th edition},
author = {John W. Jewett and Raymond A. Serway},
year = {2008},
number = {ISBN: 0-495-11240-2},
series = {Paperback},
publisher = {Thomson Learning}
}
```

This is my `.bst` file:

https://gist.github.com/rmagni/86813d2eb62ccf6d36e497ac21d425e2

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,dvipsnames,twoside,openright]{memoir} 

\usepackage[english]{varioref}              
\usepackage{natbib} 

\bibpunct[,]{[}{]}{;}{a}{,}{,}              
\bibliographystyle{Harvard}         

\begin{document}

This is a citation. \citep{fysikbog}.

\begingroup
\raggedright
\bibliography{litteratur}                           
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Thrown Error:

```
1 is an integer literal, not a string, for entry fysikbog
while executing---line 1485 of file Harvard.bst
(There was 1 error message)
```

Not sure what the relevant part of this is, but this is the part around line 1485 which the error message mentions:

```
EXECUTE {begin.bib}

EXECUTE {init.state.consts}

ITERATE {call.type$}

FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

Hopefully someone knows what this error means, thanks!

Comment: Please create a MWE (starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document} that shows the problem., also add the relevant part of the `js` file to the question (links are not persistent and people don't like to click on unknown links).

Comment: The link seems to be a very botched version of your `.bst` file. https://gist.github.com/rmagni/86813d2eb62ccf6d36e497ac21d425e2 seems better

Comment: Probably not the problem, but the `number` field is not meant for ISBN's.

Comment: Alright, but as you said it does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.bst` file has a faulty function definition (ll. [464-472](https://gist.github.com/rmagni/86813d2eb62ccf6d36e497ac21d425e2#file-harvard-bst-L464))

```
FUNCTION {format.year}
{ year duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
       pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
  month empty$
    extra.label *
}
```

The `month empty$` is hanging around there for no reason and causes a 1 to appear on the stack that is then not expected by the rest of the file and causes problems.

I assume the intended definition is closer to

```
FUNCTION {format.year}
{ year duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
       pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label *
}
```

Furthermore or all calls to `format.year` should be made as `format.year output` and *not* `format.year output.check`. `output.check` expects another argument that is not present in the incorrect calls. Simply replace all occurrences of `format.year output.check` with `format.year output`.

I have uploaded a corrected version, `harvard-fixed.bst`, that should work to https://gist.github.com/moewew/170dd99835c17667456738937a5d59d6. You can see the necessary changes in the [revision history](https://gist.github.com/moewew/170dd99835c17667456738937a5d59d6/revisions).

Comment: This worked perfectly! thanks a lot for even taking the time to edit the bst file!